# Explain the Adaptive Part of Adaptive Algorithms - Kalman Filter and Least Mean Square / Constant Modulus

Tags: kalman-filters, lms, unscented-kalman-filter

General questions:

- Is the Kalman filter (they have used Unscented Kalman Filter) adaptive or not? Is the Unscented Kalman Filter used in the paper an adaptive algorithm?
- Adaptive algorithms such as Constant Modulus and Least Squares are adaptive. Why? What is being adapted ? Based on my understanding, the step size is adapted and the weights as well. But I am not sure for the case of Kalman filters -- is the Kalman Gain getting adapted? Adapted to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptive Filters are called "Adaptive" when they can adapt to changes in data.
In the filters you mentioned above, which are part of the Linear Filters family the property means their coefficients are changing over time.

Linear Filters are basically weighing and summing the data.
For instance, given no prior information on data you may want to have exact weight for any data given.

Yet in most Signal Processing use cases we'd like to (Or might want to) give higher weight for each data sample according to its properties such as SNR, How good it fit the model, etc...

In the classic Kalman Filter the coefficients are set according to a model matrix - $ P $.
For Kalman filter this matrix stands for the Covariance of the estimation.
It changes according to 2 other matrices which are properties of our model and data - $ Q $ - The model confidence level matrix, $ R $ the data confidence model (For Gaussian data it is basically the SNR).

Since the algorithm support the cases those are changing over time it is called adaptive.

For instance, in the case of tracking a target using RADAR the algorithm can change the matrix $ R $ according to the SNR of the measurement.

The Recursive Least Squares have similar properties (Though it depends only on one factor, something similar to the matrix $ R $ of the Kalman Filter).
One could even see the RLS as a private case of the Kalman Filter (Or the Kalman Filter as a generalization).

There are many extension for the Kalman Filter for many cases.
The UKF (Unscented Kalman Filter) you mentioned is built to handle Non Linear cases of the Model.
But adaptive concept stays the same, the weights are changing according to properties of the Data and the Model.

Comment: So why is a classic Kalman Filter adaptive if all the covariances and gain can be computed offline?  It doesn't matter what the data is

Comment: You got it right. If you assume $ R $ and $ Q $ are constant it means the Kalman filter doesn't change its properties due to data change. It is Pseudo Adaptive in the meaning isn't constant (As the Covariance of the states improves with integration of data).

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, Pay attention that if the model is correct, namely the process is stationary, being constant while the statistical properties of the signal are constant, is the right and logical thing to do.

Comment: @Royi: Thank you for your answer, it is brief yet covers all the important points. However, one thing is unclear about Kalman filter in the last sentence of your answer--you say that the adaptive concept in Kalman filter stays the same because the weights are changing? What are the weights in Kalman Filter and does the Kalman Gain play any role in making the filter adaptive. Moreover, does the number of datapoints in LMS or CMA play any role in faster convergence? What are your thoughts on this?Can you please clarify these points? Thanks

Comment: What I meant in this sentence is simple. The Kalman Filter has the ability to adapt the weights according to the statistical properties of the input data. The only difference between Extended Filter Kalman and UKF, for that matter, is how the optimal coefficient is derived from those properties. This is something shared with all flavors of Kalman Filters around, they derive the weights according to the data properties.

Comment: Since the Kalman Filter is AR (Auto Regressive / Recursive) Filter of order 1 all this data is formed into this one parameter some call it the Kalman Gain.

Comment: The notion that the measurement noise, process noise , state transition matrix, measurement matrix, and deterministic inputs need to be constant or stationary for offline calculation is erroneous.  The terms must be known but they don't have to be static.  The Kalman Filter is optimal when these objects are known and the gain can be computed offline, without any interaction with the data.  What is an optimal algorithm supposed to adapt to?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, where did you say I said differently? Adaptive has nothing to do with "Optimal". Adaptive, in the way I perceive it, means if some change happened to the data (Which I know about) the system behavior is changing as well. Kalman Filter, Unless you change its parameters, which are 2, the $ R $ matrix and $ Q $ matrix isn't adaptive. Namely no change of its behavior happens. The other side of things is given the model is correct (Constant or not) and for each sample the $ Q $ and $ R $ matrices matches the data properties the Kalman Filter is optimal.

Comment: Usually in practice, we tune the properties of the Kalman Filter (Mainly in the notion of Bandwidth) by some data on the SNR of the measurements. This is adaptive framework.

Comment: @Royi multiplication of a signal by $e^{j \omega t}$ changes the value of data, so a heterodyne radio is adaptive? I think not.  For a pure Kalman Filter, where the only unknown is the state, the gain at each step can be computed offline without any data. This can be verified by consulting a Standard reference. In practice, one rarely knows all the parameters but dynamic behavior in of itself is not adaptive.  Tuning a filter is an adaptive engineering process, that doesn't make the filter adaptive, I would tend to think the opposite

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz, I don't get your point. What's your point? Kalman Filter is adaptive framework. In practice, as I wrote, people are tuning the Kalman Filter parameters for different cases. For instant, by the SNR of the Signal, by the need to be adaptive and response quickly to the changing state, etc... You can do all of that easily in the Kalman Filter framework. Now, what is your argument?

Comment: @Royi It is painfully obvious that you don't get my point.  I thought that perhaps that the case of multiplication of a signal by $e^{j\omega t}$ might be taken in the context of your perceived notion of what adaption is, would spark some reflection, but instead you doubled down on tuning.  I'm finding this conversation to depressingly ironic.  The fact that you can calculate all the gains offline, if you know the covariances, inputs, and system matrices should be enough.  The question is not:  can one make modifications to a KF that are adaptive.

Comment: If you know everything beforehand there is no need to be adaptive. There is no point the argument you made. Multiplying by $ {e}^{j \omega t} $ isn't adaptive as it doesn't change according to any property of the input. In a framework which uses Kalman Filter, RADAR for example, the Tracking System is adaptive. I gave this example, you change parameters of the filter according to the SNR. You do not know how the SNR will behave, but you can adaptively change the behavior of your tracking system according to properties of the input (Measurements of the target in this example).

Comment: Adaptive Filter, in the Signal Processing world, is the ability of a filter to change its behavior (Let's say Steady State Behavior) according to hyper parameters. So any feedback system which creates a filter based on hyper parameters (Which are set according to the input data) is adaptive. The Kalman Filter is a framework to create an AR Filter which is optimal given a model. The Kalman Filter Hyper Parameters are directly linked to the parameters of the input data. Hence, in a feedback system employing this properties it is called adaptive.

Comment: @RiaGeorge, Has the answer answered your questions? If something isn't clear, let me know.

Comment: @Royi: Thank you for your answer, I was away out of town for a few days, so could not check back on your answer. I was going through the comments and discussions here. I am quite lost, don't know what the issue and the reason for discussion is. But, I do have one last doubt which is in the last sentence you wrote "But adaptive concept stays the same, the weights "...just wanted to clarify that the weights you refer here are the weights of the adaptive filters other than Kalman as Kalman filter does not have any weights, I think.

Comment: @RiaGeorge, Kalman Filter is an AR Filter in its form. But if you calculate the equivalent FIR (Or approximate, as the FIR is infinite) you'd see its coefficients are adaptively changing according to the data properties you feed the Kalman Filter. This holds for any type of Kalman Filter (Linear, Extended, Unscented and Cubature for that matter).

Comment: @Royi: Thanks for the reply, so just to sum up if my understanding is correct or not - Kalman filter is adaptive due to the covariance Q, and R. And KAlman filter is not adaptive due to the changing nature of Kalman Gain...if Kalman gain is assumed to be changing slowly or is fixed, still the Kalman filter is adaptive. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Think of the Kalman Gain at the Filter Coefficients. Kalman Filter is adaptive since it has the property it changes its coefficients (Gain) according to data and model properties. The properties are $ Q $ and $ R $. Even if those are changed over time, it can adapt to them.

Answer (score 0):

An adaptive filter is one that updates its coefficients or parameters as a function of the input signal.  Kalman filters are adaptive filters.  On each time step, they update the estimate of the *states* they are tracking as well as the estimate of the *covariance* of these states.

Comment: The LF is an optimal state estimator. By your definition, any estimator would be adaptive. I disagree

Comment: The State Covariance, State Prediction Covariance, Innovations Covariance, Filter Gain, and Updated State Covariance can all be calculated offline without any data passing through the filter

Comment: You can have order adaptive filters too, which isn't quite covered in this answer.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz the Kalman Filter can be modified (Godard 1974) ) to work in adaptive transversal filter structures [Haykin, Adaptive filter theory, ch.6, 1986] Therefore they can implement adaptive systems. The estimated state becomes the filter coefficients. Yet in its pure classical mode it does not seem like an adaptive system as you have declared by the independence of Covariance and Gain matrices from the input data.

Comment: The offline calculation is well documented, in Bar Shaloam, Anderson and Moore, Kailath,  .., when a Kalman Filter is optimal, it is not adaptive.